# FIRST activity fullscreen android

Tags: android

I want to make my **first activity** fullscreen, not all activities, how can I do?

Answer (score 1):

call below method, before calling setcontentView(--) in oncreate method of ur Actiity which you want in full screen.

```
public void setFullScreen() {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `Manifest` file, Add `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` attribute only for the `activity` which you want to display as a full-screen.

**For example :**

```
<activity android:name=".FirstActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

To the onCreate() of the Activity you want in full screen mode.

Comment: :(     this is for make all the activities fullscreen

Comment: Try using only the first one

Comment: hhhhhh, are you try this or only you copy and paste this codes ?

Comment: I've used it in 23 published apps on the play store. I assure you it works. If other activities are becoming full screen, make sure you haven't set their theme in the manifest to full screen.

Comment: please see this picture for understand my problem http://i47.tinypic.com/2607v4l.png

Comment: Only the first one is fullscreen. I don't see how that is not what you want

Comment: @JeffBic I don't even know what the problem is. In the image you posted, your first Activity is full screen, and the second one isn't. Just as you requested.

Answer (score 0):

In onCreate method of activity that you want to be fullscreen you can use the following code.

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

write this code after setContentView